# Не запускается код телеграм-бота на пайтоне (аиограм)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Решил создать телеграм-бота для модерации чата через аиограм. Код правильный, о чём сообщает сам пайчарм. Вопрос в другом - он не запускается ни в терминале, ни через F5. Почему? (В конфиге только токен).

```
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_messages(message: types.Message):
    if 'блять' in message.text:
        await message.delete(message.text)

if __name__ == "_main_":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: В  `"__main__"` должно быть по два подчеркивания в начале и в конце. Из-за того что по одному подчеркиванию, условие никогда не выполняется, соответственно и бот не стартует.

Comment: заработало! спасибо!